# Getting number of likes for a search form

Tags: search, ruby-on-rails-5

I am struggling with the problem mentioned in the title, here is my situation:
I have a db called Picture witch has_many Relationships. Those Relationships can have the value 1 (like) or -1 (dislike), so with something like Picture.find(1).relationships.where(value: 1).count I could get the number of likes for Picture with the id 1 for example.

I am using a simple model based search, to find specific pictures. Unfortunately I don't understand how the line needs to look like, if I want to find all pictures with X number of likes or more.

```
class Search < ApplicationRecord

    def search_albums
        pics = Picture.all

        pics = pics.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{name}%") if name.present?
        pics = pics.joins(:tags).where("name LIKE ?", tag) if tag.present?
        pics = pics. ... if min_likes.present?

        return pics
    end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Ok, probably not the best solution but it works:

```
    if min_likes.present?
        stack=[]
        pics.each do |pic|
            stack.push(pic) if (pic.relationships.where(value: 1).count >= min_likes)
        end
        pics = stack
    end
```